# Upgrading Axios from 0.27.2 to 1.6.2 is breaking get requests with params. What should I do?

Tags: json, axios

I recently tried to fix all npm vulnerabilities in a project. Part of that attempt was upgrading Axios from 0.27.2 to 1.6.2.

In doing so, the format of the `params` prop for `axios.get` requests was changed. It was changed from something like:

[image]

To something like:

[image]

Source: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4999

How can I upgrade Axios but still use the same format as before?

I tried adding the following to my Axios instance, but it doesn't seem to work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Axios in 1.6.2 was sending the data fine to the server for `get` requests. My problem is that I was assuming I had to decode (parse) JSON data when objects or arrays of data were being sent for subprops of `params`.

After removing that assumption in my back-end code, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
axios.defaults.paramsSerializer = params =>
  Object.keys(params)
    .filter(key => params[key] !== undefined)
    .map(key => {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(params[key]) === "[object Object]") {
        params[key] = JSON.stringify(params[key]);
      }
      if (Array.isArray(params[key])) {
        return params[key].map((v: any) => `${key}[]=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`).join("&");
      }
      return `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`;
    })
    .join("&");
```